# CFA: Significance testing on fixed parameters

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, confirmatory-factor

In CFA for identification we fix one loading per factor, usually to 1. Then sometimes later on we are interested to do significance testing on the parameters. Below is some example AMOS output from Arbuckle (2013).

[image: Arbuckle example of CFA]

The *** represents a p-value < .001. No p-value is generated for the fixed parameters.

1. Is the notion of an estimated Standard Error for a fixed parameter inherently nonsensical?
2. Let's say I want to test the significance of all my parameters. Is it legitimate for me to move the fixed parameters around from model fit to model fit, so as to ensure that we get significance tests for all paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Is the notion of an estimated Standard Error for a fixed parameter inherently nonsensical?

Yes, I'm afraid that it is. You have fixed the parameter - it has no sampling variation. It will always have the same value.

2. Is it legitimate for me to move the fixed parameters around from model fit to model fit.

No. Changing the model changes all of the parameters.

What you can do (in this case, not every case) is identify the variance of the latent variable by constraining it to 1, and freeing the loadings.

Comment: Thanks for this great response. For the benefit of any future readers of this thread I will note here that I've made [a related question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/274345/cfa-fix-one-loading-per-factor-or-fix-the-variance-of-the-factors) regarding this issue of fixing loadings vs fixing variances.